# Qt passes an unwanted argument to a slot

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals-slots

```
def connect(signal):
    def result(func):
        signal.connect(func)
        return func
    return inner

def safemode(msg):
    def inner(func):
        @wraps(func):
        def result(*args, **kwargs):
            print 'Args passed to func:', args, kwargs
            try:
                func(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                print msg
        return result
    return inner

@connect(form.my_action.triggered)
@safemode('Something bad'?)
def my_action():
    print 'Something good!'
```

So, when I trigger the action, I see:

```
Args passed to func: (False,) {}
Something bad?
```

Since `my_action` takes no arguments, calling `func(*args, **kwargs)` where `func` is `my_action` fails.

I know one solution is to just remove the `*args, **kwargs` but I'd like to use the same decorator for both Qt GUI functions and non-GUI functions.

The stack trace isn't very helpful; it just shows `app.exec_()` then the line where the failure occurs.

Where is that `False` coming from and how can I fix it?

Comment: Not too sure about the python part, but I'd assume it's the bool argument of `triggered(bool)`, see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qaction.html#triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of commonly-used signals with parameters that pass a default value. This includes [QAction.triggered](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#triggered) and [QAbstractButton.clicked](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#clicked).

Effectively, these signals have two overloads as far PyQt is concerned: one that passes the default value, and one that doesn't. PyQt has a mechanism for explicitly choosing which one to use - but if it is not used, it will fall back to a hard-coded default. For the the above two signals, the default overload is the one that *does* pass a default value.

To select the overload which *doesn't* pass a value, do this:

```
form.my_action.triggered[()]
```

(NB: The *getitem* syntax of signal objects usually takes a *type*, or tuple of *types*, so an empty tuple is required to explicitly select an overload that has no parameters).